# "SyntaxError: import not found" with ES6 babel-compiled module

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I have the following project structure:

```
├── node_modules
│   └── (dependencies, etc.)
├── dist
│   └── bundle.js
├── src
│   └── bundle.js
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── .babelrc
├── package-lock.json
└── package.json
```

My `.babelrc` contains the following:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

I have the following included in my `package.json`:

```
"browserslist": "defaults and supports es6-module"
```

My source `bundle.js` contains the following:

```js
const foo = "foo";
export default foo;
```

My distribution `bundle.js` contains the following when compiled with babel:

```js
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports["default"] = void 0;
var foo = "foo";
var _default = foo;
exports["default"] = _default;
```

I import this compiled bundle in my `main.js`:

```js
import foo from "/dist/bundle.js";
console.log(foo);
```

And then include `main.js` at the bottom of the `body` tag in `index.html`

```html
<script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
```

After running the page, the console gives me the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default

I do not think that I am configuring babel correctly, but I cannot figure out out to do so properly. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're using ES6 module syntax in the browser, but the file you're importing has been transpiled *not* to use ES6 module syntax. Note that if you paste your source `bundle.js` file into `dist/bundle.js` it works fine.

One way to fix this is to change your `.babelrc` file as follows, so that the module syntax won't be transpiled:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

An alternative approach would be to also transpile `main.js`, and remove the `type="module"` from your script tag.